# Why can't I use @ to replace the long relative path in my __tests__ folder?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

[image]

I initialed my vue project via vue-cli.
I can use `@` in my `src` folder, but it doesn't work in my `__tests__` folder.
I've already added config in my `tsconfig.json` file, but I'm not sure whether it's for this situation.

```json
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["src/*"]
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test framework needs to be configured with the path aliases as well. It's not automatically configured with `tsconfig.json` or `vue.config.js` (or any other config).

To configure the path alias in Jest, use the [`moduleNameMapper` option](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring):

```js
// <projectRoot>/jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: [
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  ]
}
```

This is normally configured for you if using [`@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/846e143/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/default/jest-preset.js), but if you've setup Jest on your own without the plugin, you would need the config mentioned above.